# Adding accounts-ui not displaying with Leaderboard example

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react

I took this example implementation of using React with Meteor and wanted to add something simple like adding a blaze login:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor/tree/master/examples/leaderboard

Following this tutorial I added the Wrapper and placed it render of my app.jsx
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="outer">
  <AccountsUIWrapper />
  <div className="login">Login</div>
    <div className="logo"></div>
    <h1 className="title">Title</h1>
    <div className="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    <Dashboard tasks={this.data.tasks}
      selectedTaskId={this.state.selectedTaskId}
      onTaskSelected={this.selectTask} />
    {this.getBottomBar()}
  </div>
```

It compiles correctly with no errors but nothing shows up. Can someone help a newb out?!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Silly me forgot to add

`blaze-html-templates` to my packages.
**note I had to remove static-html because they conflicted.